# Problem in bibliography when using revtex4-1 class for publication in AIP

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I am trying to create a manuscript by using `revtex4-1` class. I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 x64. This manuscript is for publication in Physics of Fluids. The following is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[aip,pof,numerical]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\title[my title]{My title}
\thanks{Footnote to title of article.}

\author{Author1}
    \email{author1@email.com}
    \affiliation{ 
    Affiliation1.}%

\author{Author2}%
    \email{author2@email.com}
    \altaffiliation[Also at ]{Affiliation3.}
    \affiliation{Affiliation2.}

\author{Author3}
    \email{author3@email.com}
    \altaffiliation[Also at ]{Affiliation1.}
    \homepage{http://www.www.com/}
    \affiliation{%
    Affiliation3}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\pacs{Valid PACS appear here}
\keywords{Suggested keywords}
\maketitle

\section{\label{sec:level1}Introduction}
\blindtext \cite{asakawa2003cine}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{30}

\bibitem{asakawa2003cine}
        \textsc{Asakawa, D., Pappas, G., Blemker, S., Drace, J. E. and Delp, S.}
        2003
        Cine phase-contrast magnetic resonance imaging as a tool for quantification of skeletal muscle motion.
        \emph{Semin. Musculoskel. R.}
        \textbf{7}(4), 287--296.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the citation in the manuscript includes both the label and a number, as shown by the following picture.

[image]

The error I get during compilation is:

```
Undefined control sequence \blindtext \cite{asakawa2003cine}
```

The compiler produces the following logs.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.3.3)  22 JUL 2013 14:58
entering extended mode
**myAIP.tex

("D:\Files\myAIP.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.

("D:\Files\revtex4-1.cls"
Document Class: revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revt
ex4/ for documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2009 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 308.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 358.
\eqncolsep=\skip41
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfoot
note on input line 433.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 755.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count79
\@tbpen=\count80
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box26
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1786.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2046.
ltxfront[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r frontmatter package (AO,DPC)]
\c@affil=\count81
\c@collab=\count82
\absbox=\box27
ltxgrid[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count83
\output@latex=\toks14
\box@size@1=\box28
\box@size@2=\box29
\@protection@box=\box30
\@topmark@saved=\toks15
\footins@saved=\box31
\footins@recovered=\box32
\column@recovered=\box33
\pagesofar=\box34
\footsofar=\box35
\pagegrid@col=\count84
Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@newline, and
 \\  on input line 5578.
\c@part=\count85
\c@section=\count86
\c@subsection=\count87
\c@subsubsection=\count88
\c@paragraph=\count89
\c@subparagraph=\count90
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count91
\fbox@1=\box36
\c@table=\count92
\fbox@2=\box37
\c@video=\count93
\fbox@4=\box38
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box39
\widetext@bot=\box40
Class revtex4-1 Info: Selecting society aip on input line 7542.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\aip4-1.rtx"
File: aip4-1.rtx 2010/07/25 4.1r AIP substyle for REVTeX
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX society AIP selected on input line 67.
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Selecting journal pof on input line 7544.

Using journal substyle pof.

Class revtex4-1 Warning: No type size specified, using default 12.

Class revtex4-1 Info: Reading file aps12pt4-1.rtx on input line 7547.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\aps12pt4-1.rtx"
File: aps12pt4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for 
documentation)
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX pointsize 12pt selected on input line 30.
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding 12pt on input line 7547.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty"
Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty"
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip44
\bibsep=\skip45
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 695.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count94
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7549.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\revtex\revsymb4-1.sty"
Package: revsymb4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ f
or documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 119.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\blindtext\blindtext.sty"
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\xspace.sty"
Package: xspace 2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
\c@blindtext=\count95
\c@Blindtext=\count96
\c@blind@countparstart=\count97
\blind@countxx=\count98
\blindtext@numBlindtext=\count99
\blind@countyy=\count100
\c@blindlist=\count101
\c@blindlistlevel=\count102
\c@blindlist@level=\count103
\blind@listitem=\count104
\c@blind@listcount=\count105
\c@blind@levelcount=\count106
\blind@mathformula=\count107
\blind@Mathformula=\count108
\c@blind@randomcount=\count109
\c@blind@randommax=\count110
\c@blind@pangramcount=\count111
\c@blind@pangrammax=\count112
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Patching LaTeX tabular. on input line 7.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Robustifying \LaTeX's \boldmath command on input line 7.
Class revtex4-1 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 7.
Class revtex4-1 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 7.
Class revtex4-1 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 7.

("D:\Files\myAIP.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 40.
 [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@backout 
                       {\@citeb \@extra@b@citeb }\advance \@tempcnta by\@ne ...
l.43 \blindtext \cite{asakawa2003cine}
                                      .
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


("D:\Files\myAIP.bbl") [2]
("D:\Files\myAIP.aux")

 *File List*
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for 
documentation)
  aip4-1.rtx    2010/07/25 4.1r AIP substyle for REVTeX
aps12pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
 documentation)
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
   myAIP.bbl
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2413 strings out of 493921
 32531 string characters out of 3144877
 92955 words of memory out of 3000000
 5742 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 8532 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,6n,23p,187b,199s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/
Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Pro
gram Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><C:/Program
 Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Fil
es (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss12.pfb><C:/Program Files
 (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb><C:/Program Files (x
86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x
86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb>
Output written on myAIP.pdf (2 pages, 117817 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 49 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

The following is also the log of running `bibtex`:

```
Process started: bibtex "myAIP"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: myAIP.aux
The style file: aipnum4-1.bst
Database file #1: myAIPNotes.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "asakawa2003cine"
control{REVTEX41Control}, control.key{N/A}, control.author{N/A}, control.editor{N/A}, control.title{N/A}, control.pages{N/A}, control.year{N/A}, control.eprint{N/A}, 
control{aip41Control}, control.key{N/A}, control.author{N/A}, control.editor{N/A}, control.title{0}, control.pages{1}, control.year{N/A}, control.eprint{N/A}, 
Warning--jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1
merlin.mbs aipnum4-1.bst 2010-07-25 4.21a (PWD, AO, DPC) hacked
Control: key (0) 
Control: author (8) initials jnrlst
Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
Control: production of article title (0) allowed
Control: page (1) range
Control: year (1) truncated
Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
(There were 2 warnings)

Process exited normally
```

As can be seen from the above log, `bibtex` complains about `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "asakawa2003cine"` and uses `Database file #1: myAIPNotes.bib`. I should also mention that the directory in which my manuscript is there contains the following files before compilation:

```
myAIP.tex        
revtex4-1.cls
```

After I compile, the following files are created:

```
myAIP.aux        
myAIP.bbl        
myAIP.blg        
myAIP.log        
myAIP.pdf        
myAIP.synctex.gz 
myAIP.tex        
myAIPNotes.bib   
revtex4-1.cls
```

I don't know why `myAIPNotes.bib` is also created. The content of `myAIPNotes.bib` is as follows:

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{aip41Control,pages="1",title="0"}
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: You have used `hyperref` in a previous compilation. Remove the auxiliary files and try again.

Comment: @egreg: I have removed the auxiliary files several times. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: The MWE successfully generated PDF without any problem. Also, all the packages listed in the log-file matches with the packages in my machine.

Comment: @JagathAR: What could be the problem? How can I track back the cause of problem to produce the pdf with the correct citation?

Comment: @Ahm: Can you try this one: Remove "D:\Files\myAIP.bbl". That file is not with me :-) Also, **do not run bibtex for this time**  (reference entry is already in the TeX file).

Comment: @JagathAR: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: I modified my posted question: after I compile the `.tex` file, a file called `myAIPNotes.bib` is created. Also `bibtex` complains about `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "asakawa2003cine"` and uses `Database file #1: myAIPNotes.bib`. Can this be helpful in finding the solution to the problem I have?

Comment: the undefined command shown in the actual message is not the one you give in your description. it is ` \Hy@backout ` which means that your auxiliary files are assuming hyperref. Delete the .aux .out  .anything else files and re-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the following code to solve the problem.

```
\makeatletter
\let\Hy@backout\@gobble
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```